# Change background color when clicked textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I like for the textbox to change the background when the textbox has focus (if clicked with a mouse, tabbed into, etc).

I don't like the textchange method since it won't change until one character has been added.

```
private void txtFoo_OnGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFoo.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
        txtBar.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work for me.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Did you also subscribe the event handler?

Answer (score 1):

Like Ben said... did you subscribe to the event handler?

Is your code even executing? You can put a break point in there and check pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the *Enter* event instead

```
private void txtFoo_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtFoo.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
    txtBar.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txtWFileNo.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "silver");
```